# Is python incredibly inefficient at for loops, or is it just my code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, pythagorean

My question isn't really about my code, but python in general. We had a race of coding in my family, and my parents coded their version of this project in C# and javascript respectively. I thought python was meant to be as efficient, if not more so than other languages. We ended up writing the same code  (different syntax obviously), but their files ran within milliseconds (221 from my Dad on Javascript and 500 from my Mum in C#) and mine ran within about 5 minutes. This is a ridiculous difference, and makes me question how on earth python is ever applied in real-world data processing and algorithm solving.

---

I have solved a problem using pythagorean number triplets. The problem goes, if a squared + b squared = c squared, there is only one combination of a, b and c that add to make a thousand. Finish by printing the numbers required to make 1000, timesed together.

```
for c in range(1000, 0, -1):
        for a in range(1000, 0, -1):
            for b in range(1000, 0, -1):
                if (a*a)+(b*b)==(c*c):
                    if a+b+c == 1000:
                        print("I have found it")
                        print(a*b*c)
                        quit()
```

Comment: The above will run a total of a billion iterations. The above is not an efficient way to find the solution.

Comment: Your dad solved this a different way... But the answer to your question is that Python is slow... but not *that* slow

Comment: Plus you are needlessly recalculating both a^2 and c^2.

Comment: To everyone asking if my parents used the same algorithm - they did. But still python was extortionately slower! Thanks to all answers so far :)

Comment: To do data processing in python you (1) use smarter algorithms (you are doing a lot of redundant computations here) and (2) do the heavy looping in other languages like C or Fortran.

Comment: @H4KKR Strictly speaking the answer to your question is that *speed is not a property of the language*. Programming languages, but the lowest level machine instructions, don't do anything. They only get translated into other languages, and eventually into machine code. In principle this translation step could take you from your code to your parent's. Even more, in theory the translation could take you from your code to the more efficient algorithms that you were given too. It is the different translations into machine code the ones that generate more or less efficient code.

Answer (score 6):

Python is usually less efficient compared to languages that are statically typed. Besides being dynamically typed, Python is very dynamic in several other aspects, like long chains of fallbacks for certain operations, `for` loops that work on any iterable, context managers, etc. that can work on a very broad set of objects. These features make programming convenient, but frequently come with a certain cost. A Python program that is optimized will therefore frequently be outperformed by an equivalent program in C++, Haskell, Java, etc.

But I think the main problem is that your algorithm is not very efficient. It here has three loops that each range over 999 items. This thus means that the inner loops are performed at most 997'002'999 times. We can rewrite the algorithm such that it will at most take 499'500 iterations as follows:

```
for c in range(1000, 0, -1):
    for a in range(999-c, 0, -1):
        b = 1000-a-c
        if a*a + b*b == c*c:
            print("I have found it")
            print(a*b*c)
            quit()
```

Indeed, we can calculate a valid value for `b` by obtaining this from 1000-a-c. Furthermore we can restrict the range by starting to iterate from `999-c` in the range of `a`.

If we omit the `print`ing, and `quit()`ing, we obtain the following result when we run the function 1'000 times:

```
>>> timeit(f, number=1000)
27.56889909002348
```

This thus runs in 27.6 milliseconds.

Comment: Thanks for the more efficient algorithm!!

Comment: Your first sentence misses cases such as https://benchmarksgame-team.pages.debian.net/benchmarksgame/fastest/node-python3.html - Python is also less efficient compared to other dynamic languages.There are some even less efficient dynamic languages, but it's not really the sticking point for loops involving integers.

Comment: @PeteKirkham: you can not really say that a "language" is inefficient. Since, a language is just syntax, grammar, and semantics. Nothing more, nothing less. If one compares CPython with node.js, then indeed we can say that CPython usually is outperformed by node.js. That is partly, as stated in the rest of the first paragraph due to for example a long sequence of fallbacks. For example Python evaluates truthiness by first calling `__bool__`, the `__len__`, etc. and each exhaust the MRO. JavaScripts language specs defined a specific set of objects to be "falsy", which is of course simpler.

Comment: @PeteKirkham: it is furthermore noteworthy to say that Python's `for i in range(..)`is nothing "special". Range is simply an iterable, and it implements an iterator protocol (which will usually not be that fast compared to a simpler `for(var i = 0; i < n; i++)`, since then the conditions are very clear. Python's `for` can be passed any kind of iterable, and it thus has not much means to "optimize". Especially since syntactically, it is not said that `range(..)` still points to the `range(..)` builtin.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I agree your first sentence could make the distinction between language and implementations of them, but as your comments allude to, an equally good implementation of Python and JavaScript may well still result in Python being slower. "the dynamic nature of Python results in a lot of fallbacks" implies that the callbacks are due to Python being a dynamic language, yet it's rather 'the nature of Python's dynamism', a language decision, which is the cause the inefficiency,

Comment: @PeteKirkham: there is a difference between a *dynamic* language, and a dynamically *typed* language. Most dynamic languages are indeed dynamically typed languages, but usually a dynamic language is a broader term: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming_language

Comment: @PeteKirkham: I hope the edit makes it easier for readers to understand why Python sometimes is slower compared to other languages.

Answer (score 2):

You can further speed up the process by using the square sum relation of the pythagorean triplets. Seen in this implementation https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/generate-pythagorean-triplets/

I have tried it out myself with the following code and found that it runs in two-tenths of a millisecond.

```
import math
import time

def pythagoreanTriplets(limits) : 
    c, m = 0, 2

    # Limiting c would limit  
    # all a, b and c 
    while c < limits : 

        # Now loop on n from 1 to m-1 
        for n in range(1, m) : 
            a = m * m - n * n 
            b = 2 * m * n 
            c = m * m + n * n 

            # if c is greater than 
            # limit then break it 
            if limits%(a+b+c) ==0: 
              #print(1000/(a+b+c)*a,1000/(a+b+c)*b,1000/(a+b+c)*c, "Found")
              return

            print(a, b, c) 

        m = m + 1

start = time.process_time() 
pythagoreanTriplets(1000)
elapsed = time.process_time() 
elapsed = elapsed - start
print("Time spent in (function name) is: ", elapsed)
```

Efficient code, like Willem suggests, is the biggest factor here.
[image]

Updated the above code with Pete's insight.

I ran the code once with the print statement to ensure it's correctness and once without to see the speed, and it shows a decrease of about 20x!

[image]

Comment: 1/ you could return rather than break as it appears we only need one result not all of them  2/ testing for if limits % (a+b+c) == 0:  then scaling a,b,c gets the answer quicker, you could then change the generation to primitive triples only.

Comment: Yes, I have tried this out and it is significantly faster by about an order of magnitude. Once we find the triple, we divide limits by a, b, c and then scale by the result of that division to get the final answer right?

Answer (score 2):

We can make Python for loops much faster.

The poster's question was why Python "for loops" are so slow relative to C# and JavaScript. This is not addressed by coming up with a different algorithm that reduces the need for "for loops" (especially since the C# and JavaScript versions would also be faster with the modified algorithm).  In general programming languages are compared using similar algorithms with their distinction enabled by language features which allow them to excel at a task-- https://benchmarksgame-
 https://benchmarksgame-team.pages.debian.net/benchmarksgame/index.html

In this case, the task is to use Python language features to more rapidly search over a billion numbers (the size of the three nested for loops)?

Two approaches were tried to speed up the code: Cython and Numba (separately).

Setup:

- Jupyter Notebooks
- Python 3.5.2 OS
- Windows 10 64-bit
- Processor i7

Results:

1. Python 3.5.2 =>        387.356 seconds
2. Cython     =>          117.223 seconds
3. Cython (improved) =>   0.63 seconds (using @CodeSurgeon suggestion)
4. Numba     =>           0.5 seconds

The Numba version is comparable to the poster's JavaScript and C# times.
Numba provided a 774 speed up over the Pure Python using the same "sub-optimal" algorithm.  Notice all three implementation uses basically the same code as shown below.

1. Python 3.5.2 Code

```
    import time

    def solve():
        for c in range(1000, 0, -1):
            for a in range(1000, 0, -1):
                for b in range(1000, 0, -1):
                    if (a*a)+(b*b)==(c*c):
                        if a+b+c == 1000:
                            return a*b*c


    to = time.time()
    print('I have found it {}'.format(solve()))
    print("Elapsed Time\n", time.time()- t0)
```

Python 3.5.2 Output

```
I have found it 31875000
Elapsed Time
 387.3550021648407
```

2. Cython Code (see https://ipython-books.github.io/55-accelerating-python-code-with-cython/)

```
    %load_ext cython
    %%cython -a

    import time

    def solve():
        for c in range(1000, 0, -1):
            for a in range(1000, 0, -1):
                for b in range(1000, 0, -1):
                    if (a*a)+(b*b)==(c*c):
                        if a+b+c == 1000:
                            return a*b*c


    t0 = time.time()
    print('I have found it {}'.format(solve()))
    print("Elapsed Time\n", time.time()- t0)
```

Cython Output

```
I have found it 31875000
('Elapsed Time\n', 117.22299981117249)
```

3. Cython (with Cdef https://buildmedia.readthedocs.org/media/pdf/notes-on-cython/latest/notes-on-cython.pdf)

   %%cython -a

   import time

   cdef int solve():
       cdef int a, b, c

   ```
   for c in range(1000, 0, -1):
       for a in range(1000, 0, -1):
           for b in range(1000, 0, -1):
               if (a*a)+(b*b)==(c*c):
                   if a+b+c == 1000:
                       return a*b*c
   ```

   t0 = time.time()
   print('I have found it {}'.format(solve()))
   print("Elapsed Time\n", time.time()- t0)

Output (Cython using Cdef)

```
I have found it 31875000
('Elapsed Time\n', 0.6340005397796631)
```

4. Numba Code (see https://numba.pydata.org/)

```
    import time
    from numba import jit

    @jit(nopython=True)    # only need to add Numba decorator to get speed up
    def solve():
        for c in range(1000, 0, -1):
            for a in range(1000, 0, -1):
                for b in range(1000, 0, -1):
                    if (a*a)+(b*b)==(c*c):
                        if a+b+c == 1000:
                            return a*b*c


    t0 = time.time()
    print('I have found it {}'.format(solve()))
    print("Elapsed Time\n", time.time()- t0)
```

Numba Output

```
I have found it 31875000
Elapsed Time
 0.5209996700286865
```

Comment: Thanks for actually answering my question ;). I'll have a look at Numba, thank you!

Comment: @H4KKR glad I could help.  Time for Numba is even less (i.e. only 0.32 seconds) if you leave out the overhead of the compile time needed the first time the function solve is called.  This is observed by using timeit to call the solve function multiple times and averaging the calculation time.

Comment: Please don't link to those (currently) 18 months out-of-date bogus web pages! The benchmarks game is hosted at https://benchmarksgame-team.pages.debian.net/benchmarksgame/

Comment: @igouy Thanks for the tip and revised the link in my answer.  It's been months since I visited the benchmark game so just used the first the link in Google search that looked okay.  I didn't know there are multiple sites for these benchmarks with the same looking starting page.

Comment: @DarrylG Thanks. Some people scrape the pages from the benchmarks game website and use them to boost traffic to their own URLs.

Comment: The cython timing seem awfully slow! I think there is significant room for improvement by adding typing information to your counter variables (a, b, c) by making them "cdef variables".

Comment: @CodeSurgeon thanks for the tip.  I'll take a look at that.

Comment: @CodeSurgeon--with Cdef the cython timing dropped to 0.63 seconds.  Amazing the improvement just by declaring the variable types.

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a lot of repeated calculations that could be taken out of the loops so I decided to precompute the squares. 
`sqrs` as a dict performs three tasks:

1. It allows looping of x and x**2 by just iterating over `sqrs.items()`.
2. It allows lookup of if a**2 + b**2 is itself a square.
3. It allows lookup of `c` if the previous task is true.

Here's the code with timings:

```
def original():
    for c in range(1000, 0, -1):
        for a in range(1000, 0, -1):
            for b in range(1000, 0, -1):
                if (a*a)+(b*b)==(c*c):
                    if a+b+c == 1000:
                        print("I have found it")
                        print(a*b*c)
                        return

%time original()
I have found it
31875000
Wall time: 2min 27s

def pre_compute_sqrs():
    sqrs = {x**2:x for x in range(1, 1001)}
    for aa, a in sqrs.items():
        for bb, b in sqrs.items():
            ab, aabb = a + b, aa + bb
            if ab >= 1000 or aabb >= 1_000_000:
                break
            if aabb not in sqrs:
                continue
            c = sqrs[aabb]
            if a+b+c == 1000:
                print("I have found it")
                print(a*b*c)
                return

%time pre_compute_sqrs()
I have found it
31875000
Wall time: 46.9 ms
```

Is Python slow? It can be.

Is it usually too slow? No, not usualy.

Comment: @DarrylG's timings for the base Python are around half as fast as my base timings. Using the same factor, my plain Python refactoring is ~5x faster than Numba; but relies on finding a better way to do the calculation rather than doing it the same way but faster.